# How to add restriction for intermediate nodes in cypher statement

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I wrote a cypher statement to find out all nodes which have relations to Node `n` within depth < 5 and have restriction that node's `property1 < 100`.

```
MATCH (n:NodeLable)-[:REL*1..5]-(m:NodeLable)
WHERE m.property1 < 100
return m
```

But if I'd like to restrict intermediate node's property too, how could I modify my cypher statement?

A example to describe my purpose: when above cypher returned node m1 which is connected to n as: `(n)-[:REL]-(int1)-[:REL]-(m1)` or `(n)-[:REL*1..3]-(int1)-[:REL*1..3]-(m1)`, how could I add restrict to all intermediate nodes like `int1.property2 < 50`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
MATCH path=(n:NodeLable)-[:REL*1..5]-(m:NodeLable)
WHERE
  m.property1 < 100 AND
  ALL(node IN nodes(path) WHERE node.property2 < 50)
RETURN m
```

If you want to exclude `n` from that, you should specify `nodes(path)[1..]` instead of `nodes(path)`.  If you want to exclude `m` you can do `nodes(path)[1..-1]`

Comment: Thanks, Brian. Your code sample is exactly what I want. However, during my test, I found if set depth to 4 it return Null soon, but it takes much much longer time if set depth to 5 although result is Null too. I'm curious that should depth 5 return soon? Because if there is already no nodes on depth 4, it's definitely no node on depth 5.

Comment: ;(  Yeah, the problem with queries like this is that you first gather all paths of length 5 and the evaluate them.  You could probably build out a more complicated query that checked one path length size first and moved on only if there were results.  You might look into an unmanaged extension to calculate it more efficiently in Java.  Also in Neo4j 3.0 stored procedures would allow you to build some Java code and then get the result via Cypher

Comment: Would you please share some key words or sample link about "checked xxx first and moved on only if xxx"? Could this be done by pure cypher? Seems it's not supported in cypher that a statement like "if...else...", except in RETURN? @Brian

Comment: if/else is kind of supported with `CASE`, but yeah, maybe it's not possible ;)  At least not in a way that I'd want to maintain...